# How to find first day of current month in calculated column in SAP HANA SP12

Tags: sql, hana

How to find the first day of the current month in a calculated column in SAP HANA SP12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in calculation view:

```
adddays(lastday(addmonths(now(),-1)),1)
```

Comment: Hi, if possible, it's always nice to explain *why* your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In format '2018-04-01' it will be:

leftstr(now(),8)+'01'

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the To_Date() function and the other option is using user-defined [SQLScript First_Day function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/first-day-of-month-sqlscript-date-function.aspx)

Here is how you can use both of them

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE(
  YEAR(current_date) || '/' || MONTH(current_date) || '/' || '1', 'YYYY/MM/DD'
  ) as "First Day",
FIRST_DAY(current_date) as "First_Day"
 FROM DUMMY
```